# JavaScript: accessing an object with properties which can be undefined

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to access an JavaScript object like this:

```
var a = {};
a.propertyA.propertyB;
```

where `a.propertyA` is of course `undefined`, but I'd like to write `a.propertyA.propertyB` assuming `a.propertyA` is not `undefined`. If `a.propertyA` is `undefined`, I expect `a.propertyA.propertyB` also to be `undefined`.

I'm developing with complicate objects, so sometimes I feel like accessing objects with multiple properties at once. I wonder there's a kind of `get` method that can be given a default value.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no built-in operator or function for that. So you're stuck in using some of the 3rd party libraries.

Comment: this has been asked before. and what you need to do is use a string

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to do this without using string literals first, to ensure it exists, or create the chain if necessary.

```js
/**
 * Define properties to be objects on a root object if they dont' exist
 *
 * @param o the root object
 * @param m a chain (.) of names that are below the root in the tree
 */
function ensurePropertyOnObject(o, m)
{
    var props = m.split('.');
    var item;
    var current = o;

    while(item = props.shift()) {
        if(typeof o[item] != 'object') {
            current[item] = {};
        }
        current = o[item];
    }    
}

var a = new Object
ensurePropertyOnObject(a, "propertyA.propertyB");
a.propertyA.propertyB = "ho";
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

try using something like this:

```
function get(a){
    if (a.propertyA === undefined){
        a.propertyA = {propertyB: undefined};
    }
    else{
        //do whatever with a.propertyA.propertyB
    }
    return a; //or whatever you'd like to return
}
```